# Google App Engine server side library

Tags: api, google-app-engine, cloud

I've a server side Google App Engine dependent library project.
On GAE 1.8.3 it was building fine.

I've updated to the last GAE version 1.8.9, and now I get an error:

There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: Project is not a web-app project

What I've done is disable the "Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints builder".
Now it builds fine with no errors.

It is just a helper classes and functions library for GAE projects that don't use Cloud Endpoints at all.
Is there any problem doing that?

Thanks

Comment: If it ain't broke no more don' fix it...  There is no problem with that, perhaps it's actually better.  Anecdotally, after an AppEngine SDK upgrade I have sometimes had build errors that were fixed by clearing the "Use Google App Engine" property, saving, and then setting it again.